# Website loading slow in Safari (sometimes doesn't even load) and background images not showing up

Tags: macos, safari, background-image

I have a website which displays fine in IE, Chrome, FF and even on Chrome on Mac but it doesn't work on Safari on Mac.
Here's what happens.

1. When I open the home page, most of the page loads but not full. It keeps loading. So if I refresh the page, it opens instantly
2. No background image is being displayed
3. If I go to new page, it sometimes load very quickly but sometimes it doesn't load like point 1 above and I had to refresh it (sometimes even refreshing doesn't work so it is all random)

Safari version is 7.0.1 and OS is Max OS 10.9.1

This is one of the shitiest browser I have seen.

Comment: Setting aside your clear lack of history if this is the worst browser you've ever seen, have you tried pulling up the debug window and seeing why things aren't loading correctly?  Try `Preferences > Advanced > Show Develop menu in menu bar` and look for errors and check out the resource timeline.  Also, make sure you've got any Extensions disabled in the browser so you have a clean test.

Comment: Yes this is the worst browser because the site is working on all major browsers including Chrome on Mac. Thanks for the tip, let me check that develop menu and see how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, i solved this issue adding google dns 8.8.8.8 in the System Preferences > Network > Advanced > DNS. 
I also tried empty the Safari cache, but it's not help.